# How to make regasm use assembly redirecting?

Tags: app-config, .net-assembly, regasm

I try to run regasm but it complains it cannot find given library. That is true because it does not exist, however for that reason I used assembly redirecting in app.config to point out which version should be used.

It seems regasm ignores app.config or redirecting -- is there a way to make it use those entries for version redirecting?

Comment: You are just getting a heads-up for what is going to go wrong when the client app tries to use your library as well.  It doesn't know that it needs an app.config file.  Nor does it know where to find the DLL that you are trying to redirect.  You'll have to get past the Regasm hump by not needing the DLL at all.  It uses Reflection to find types, crystal ball says that you have a `static` variable with an initializer that requires that other DLL.  Initialize it in the constructor instead, favor Lazy.

Comment: @HansPassant, as not-needing the DLL is not possible, because I do need it :-) But you are right about app.config, could you please post it as regular answer so I can accept it? Thank you.